# Using @font-face in HTML style attribute (CSS inline style) not working

Tags: html, css, font-face

I want to use `Devlys010` font in my HTML `textarea`.

I have downloaded ttf for the same and copy it in the project folder.

In `textarea` code I'm using the following code:

`<textarea class="form-control" name="question" style="font-family:DevLys_010; src: url('mfdev010.ttf');"></textarea>`

But it is not showing the devlys font while typing in the text box.

Please help me how can I use this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call your font from the `style` element in your `head` section, or from an external CSS file.

I don't believe you can load the file from the `style` attribute.

Try something along these lines:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title> text here </title>
        <style>
            @font-face {
                font-family: "DevLys_010";
                src: url("https:// path here / path here /mfdev010.ttf");
            }
            textarea {
                font-family: DevLys_010;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="question"></textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```